# Accessing elements from a lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to access my WPF element from a lambda expression.

Here is my simplified code:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public Rectangle MyRectangle {get; set;}
        public Button MyButton {get; set;}

        public void MyVoid()
        {
            MyRectangle = new Rectangle();
            MyRectangle.Width = 300;
            MyRectangle.Height = 100;
            MyGrid.Children.Add(MyRectangle);

            MyButton = new Button();
            MyButton.Widht = 200;
            MyButton.Height = 200;
            MyButton.Click += (a, e) =>
            {
                MyRectangle.Fill = Brushes.Red;
            }
            MyGrid.Children.Add(MyButton);
        }
    }
}
```

But there is an error with MyRectangle in "MyButton.Click" :

> Anonymous methods, lambda expressions, and query expressions in
>   structs cannot access instance members of "this".

Can someone explain how to fix this error?

Comment: Change the struct to a class

Comment: @Sean This is the solution - but please explain it for him.

Answer (score 1):

The easy fix, as per @Sean said, change `struct` to `class`.

If it has to be `struct`, you need to deference `this` to a local variable:

```
MyStruct self = this;

MyButton.Click += (a, e) =>
{
    // Assuming Rectangle here is System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle
    self.MyRectangle.Fill = Brushes.Red;
}
```

I can also give you some explanation about the error:

[The error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1673) is because `this` which is effectively `ref this` in `struct` is a pointer which cannot be captured and stored in [`Delegate.Target`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.target?view=netcore-3.1).

In order to get `this` captured by a delegate, you will need to dereference `this` to a local variable and capture the value in the variable.

However, when you do the above, the compiler creates a defensive copy, meaning `self` is a copy of the struct where `this` points to. This means, whilst you can still make changes to fields / properties whose return types are reference types, any changes made to `self` instance itself as well as those value type returning fields / properties won't be reflected in `this`.

Comment: _Any changes made to self won't be reflected in this._ If `Rectangle` is a class the changes should be visible over all copies of this struct, isn't it?

Comment: @SebastianSchumann Yes, with *any changes made to self* I meant changes made to the `self` instance itself. Any changes made to reference type instances stored in the struct can still be modified.

Comment: [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/buEnFP) The hack (sorry) of dereferencing `this` to `self` works.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann The demo works because your `Rectangle` is a class. So both self and this references the same `Rectangle` class instance. I didn't see the OP is coding WPF, I was thinking System.Drawing.Rectangle, which is a struct. I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes. That't the only way where changes are visible to external usages. If `Rectangle` is struct you can`t even compile - at least the online compiler doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution did not work for me. To solve the problem, I deleted the anonymous method and created another one outside of the "MyVoid" method.